# Reading Highscorelist from text file into a textBox sorted by score

Tags: c#, winforms, list, text-files

I've programmed a Game. In the Game, the player collected Points, as next step the player can write his Name in a textBox and by clicking on the "Send" Button, his Name and his Points are getting saved in a .txt file.

The player can read the Highscore of him or other Player Names in a textBox which reads out the Name and Score of the saved text file.
The text file looks like:

```
[Name]     [Points]
 Name1      60
 Name2      20
 Name3      90
 Name4      80
```

As you can see, my problem is, that the text file isn't sorted by the scores. How can I program the `TextBox` or the text file that the Player with the Highest Number is first, 2nd etc.?

Current Code:

```
using System.IO;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        s_Textfile = "Highscore.txt";
        StreamWriter o_StreamW;
        if (!File.Exists(s_Textfile))
        {
            o_StreamW = File.CreateText(s_Textfile);
            o_StreamW.Close();
        }
        string s_Spacebar = "";
        s_Name = PlayersName.Text; //The Name the player wrotes in the textBox
        s_Highscore = Points.Text; //The Points the Player has

        o_StreamW.WriteLine(s_Name + s_Spacebar+ s_Highscore);
        o_StreamW.Close();
 }
```

And here what my Highscore `TextBox` currently looks like:

```
StreamReader o_StreamR;
string s_Line = "";
string s_AllLines = "";

o_StreamR = new StreamReader(GameOverScreen.s_Textfile);
while (o_StreamR.Peek() != -1)
{
    s_Line= o_StreamR.ReadLine();
    s_AllLines = s_AllLines + s_Line + "\r\n";
}
o_StreamR.Close();
HighscoreRichTextBox.Text += "Name:             Score:" + "\r\n";
HighscoreRichTextBox.Text += s_AllLines;
```

Comment: All your posts have a score of 0 or less.  Now would be a good time to read [ask], take the [tour] and perhaps visit the [help] to learn how the site works, how to ask a good question etc before the site throttles your account.  There doesnt seem to be any code there to sort anything, so there isnt anything to help with yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first use a tab as the separator for your player Name and Score as it is easier to parse.   Create a struct holding the score and name, then read in the contents of the file, create the list, sort and output.

```
    //struct to hold the values
    struct highScoreEntry
    {
        public string PlayerName;
        public string Score;
        public highScoreEntry(string playerName, string playerScore)
        {
            PlayerName = playerName;
            Score = playerScore;
        }
    }



    List<highScoreEntry> allScores = new List<highScoreEntry>();
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Path to file"))
    {
        //skip the first line name and score titles
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] lineParts = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            allScores.Add(new highScoreEntry(lineParts[0], lineParts[1]));
        }

    }
    'sort in descending order using OrderByDescending
    List<highScoreEntry> sortedList = allScores.OrderByDescending(i => i.Score).ToList<highScoreEntry>();
    string highScoreText = "Player\tScore\r\n";
    foreach (highScoreEntry item in sortedList)
    {
        ''can be written directly into the textbox but for the example write it to a string
        highScoreText += item.PlayerName + "\t" + item.Score + "\r\n";
    }
    //add it to the textbox
    HighscoreRichTextBox.Text = highScoreText;

    }
```